# And-Or in MDX queries

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

Please consider this `MDX` query:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,  
[Date].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON ROWS  
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

How Can I add `WHERE` clause to above query with these three criteria:

**1)** Where `[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States] AND [Product].[Category].&[Bike]`

**2)** Where `[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States] OR [Product].[Category].&[Bike]`

**3)** Where `([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States] OR [Product].[Category].&[Bike]) AND [Date].[Year].&[2008]`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Where [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]
>   AND [Product].[Category].&[Bike]

For this your where clause will be

```
Where ([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States], [Product].[Category].&[Bike])
```

The above code defines a tuple which consits of data on from United States Bikes Sales

> 2) Where [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States] OR
>   [Product].[Category].&[Bike]

For this your Where clause will be

```
Where 
{([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States], [Product].[Category].defaultmember),
([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].[Country], [Product].[Category].&[Bike])}
```

In this case you want data when either the country is USA or the Product is bike. So I have defined two tuples the first one says that country is USA and the product category can be any product category. In the next tuple I say that the country can be any country but the product is Bike. In MDX each Tuple with in a set should be equal in terms of hierarchy and in terms of the position of hierarchy. In the above case i cannot make a set saying

```
{
([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]),
([Product].[Category].&[Bike])
}
```

This Set is not possible in MDX, therefore in the first tuple I mentioned 
"[Product].[Category].defaultmember" which means no particular value is defined, similarly in the next tuple i used "[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].[Country]" since this is user hierarchy I cannot use default member, so I used this expression.

> 3) Where ([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]
>   OR [Product].[Category].&[Bike]) AND [Date].[Year].&[2008]

For this you need to modify the where clause and the on rows. So for this part your query will be

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,  
    [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2011] ON ROWS -- in my sample the strong name of 2011 is &[2011] yours may be diffrent 
    FROM [Adventure Works] 
    Where 
    {([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States], [Product].[Category].defaultmember),
    ([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].[Country], [Product].[Category].&[Bike])}
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain why you use `[Product].[Category].defaultmember` and `[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].[Country], [Product].[Category].&[Bike])`? I don't understand the logic of your answer

Comment: @Arian i have edited the answer to add explanation. Incase you are still confused contact me on skype (id: moazrub)