# Mdx Query axis specification

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube

Welcome to everyone.
I would be very thanks if anyone help me. I am not too expert writing mdx query.
I am working in a software that build a mdx query to get info from a OLAP structure.
I get the result when I filter by a dimension, but I need to filter by many.

my structure is
CodGer : A, B, C, D
CodModel : A01, A02, A03, B01, B02,B03 ...

With this query I get all element from A1, and that is right.

```
Select {[Measures].allmembers} on columns
, non empty { 
[ModelosGers].[CodGer].[A]   *
 {[ModelosGers].[CodModel].[A01] }  } on rows
 From [Tasas] 
where {[Periodos].[Periodos].[Periodos].[260]}
```

But, in fact, I also need, for example, get all element from A and B01.
In sql could be like

```
 Select * from Tasas where [Periodos].[Periodos].[Periodos]=260 and( [ModelosGers].[CodGer] like 'A' or  [ModelosGers].[CodModel]='B01')
```

I have been research filters and where clause MDX but I do obtain the right query.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved my selft traying differents posts like
[And-Or in MDX queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694504/and-or-in-mdx-queries)

```
Select {[Measures].allmembers} on columns
, non empty {
{([ModelosGers].[CodGer].[A] ,[ModelosGers].[CodModelo].defaultmember ) ,
([ModelosGers].[CodGer].defaultmember ,[ModelosGers].[CodModelo].[B01]  ) }
} on rows
 From [Tasas] where {[Periodos].[Periodos].[Periodos].[260]}
```